# Archivo ".ini" para conexión OLE DB a SQLSERVER

Tags: powerbuilder

Buenas estoy tratando de hacer una conexión a SQLSERVER desde Power Builder desde un archivo .ini,
a través de OLE DB, cuando hago la conexión directa en el Power Builder es decir pongo el codigo de conexion en la ventana de Aplicación conecta bien, pero cuando paso los parametros a un archivo ini falla la conexión, el código que estoy utilizando es este

Archivo.ini
[Database]

```
DBMS = "OLE DB"
LogPass = "1234"
LogId = "Servidor"
AutoCommit = False
DBParm = "PROVIDER='SQLOLEDB',DATASOURCE='Mipc',PROVIDERSTRING='database=Sistema'"
```

Parámetros de conexión en PB

```
gtr_datos = CREATE TRANSACTION
gtr_datos.DBMS = ProfileString("Archivo.ini", "Database", "DBMS", "")
gtr_datos.DBParm = 
profilestring("Archivo.ini","Database","DBParm","none")
CONNECT Using gtr_datos;

if  gtr_datos.sqlcode=0 then
    messagebox("SIs","Conexión con la Base de Datos Exitosa")
    open(w_inicio)   

else
messagebox("Mensaje","No se pudo Conectar con la Base de Datos")
end if
```

Que puede estar fallando? de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Debes de indicar la ruta completa del archivo .ini, ejemplo `C:/Archivo.ini`

Comment: @javdromero, Gracias por ayuda, funciono